# How to run fixture once for each run of other fixture

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

Conftest.py

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def fixture2(request):
    do something

@pytest.fixture(scope="session", params=[ 1, 2, 3 ])
def fixture1(request):
    do something else
```

test_file.py

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures('fixture2', 'fixture1')
class TestSomething1(object):
    def test_1(self):
        pass

    def test_2(self):
        pass

@pytest.mark.usefixtures('fixture1')
class TestSomething2(object):
    def test_3(self):
        pass

    def test_4(self):
        pass
```

what happens is I get 3 sets of tests (1 set for each invocation of fixture1), but fixture2 only runs once for all 3 sets of tests (at least thats my understanding). I'm not sure how to make it run once for each run of fixture1 (not once for each test).

What I ended up doing:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def fixture2(request, fixture1):
    do something

@pytest.fixture(scope="session", params=[ 1, 2, 3 ])
def fixture1(request):
    do something else
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `@pytest.fixture(scope="module")` to something else like `@pytest.fixture(scope="class")` or `@pytest.fixture(scope="function")`.
Module scope means its run once per module.

From the fixture arguments documentation:

> scope – the scope for which this fixture is shared, one of "function"
>   (default), "class", "module", "package" or "session".
>
> "package" is considered experimental at this time.

[Pytest documentation on scopes](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#scope-sharing-a-fixture-instance-across-tests-in-a-class-module-or-session)

make fixture1 dependant on fixture2 and use the same scopes if you want one fixture to be called once for each time the other is called.

Comment: whats the difference between module and session and class?

Comment: @4c74356b41 It's described in the documentation that is linked

Comment: i dont see anything about that in there

Comment: @4c74356b41 From the docs: We can add scope="module" to our fixture function to only be invoked once per test module (the default is to invoke once per test function). Multiple test functions in a test module will thus each receive the same fixture instance, thus saving time. If you decide that you rather want to have a session-scoped fixture instance, you can simply declare it: scope="session". Finally, the class scope will invoke the fixture once per test class.

Comment: i guess in this case the question is, what is a test module? because I dont see any difference between a module and session scope with this explanation

Comment: @4c74356b41 The module is per file basis and session is per test session as in all tests that you run.

Comment: one more question, though, if I add another class that needs fixture2, will it invoke fixture2 one time per class? because i need it to be invoked one time per fixture1, not per class or test

Comment: Then make fixture1 dependant on fixture2 and use the same scopes